# Asp.net Core 2 and Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Good morning I'm trying to add Anti Forgery Token to my application made using Knockout.js
This is my Model:

```
    public partial class Course 
    { 
        [Key] 
        public int CourseID { get; set; } 
        public string CourseName { get; set; } 
        public string CourseDescription { get; set; } 
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
        // POST: Home/Create 
        [HttpPost] 
        public string Create(Course course) 
        { 
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return "Model is invalid"; 
            _db.Courses.Add(course); 
            _db.SaveChanges(); 
            return "Cource is created"; 
        }
```

This is my View:

```
@model MVCCRUDKnockout.Models.Course 

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Create"; 
} 

<div class="form-horizontal"> 
    <h4>Course</h4> 
    <hr> 

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CourseName">CourseName</label> 
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="CourseName" name="CourseName" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: CourseName"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CourseDescription">CourseDescription</label> 
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="CourseDescription" name="CourseDescription" type="text" value="" data-bind="value: CourseDescription"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"> 
            <input type="button" data-bind="click: createCourse" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 

<div> 
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Read") 
</div> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/KOScripts/KOCreate.js"></script>
```

This is my Script:

```
$(function () { 
    ko.applyBindings(modelCreate); 
}); 
var modelCreate = { 
    CourseName: ko.observable(), 
    CourseDescription: ko.observable(), 
    createCourse: function () { 
        try { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/Home/Create', 
                type: 'post', 
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: ko.toJSON(this), //Here the data wil be converted to JSON 
                contentType: 'application/json', 
                success: successCallback, 
                error: errorCallback 
            }); 
        } catch (e) { 
            window.location.href = '/Home/Read/'; 
        } 
    } 
}; 

function successCallback(data) { 
    window.location.href = '/Home/Read/'; 
} 
function errorCallback(err) { 
    window.location.href = '/Home/Read/'; 
}
```

Now I try to change the code:

1) adding [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] to the controller;

2) adding @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to the View.

My problem is that I cannot edit the Script to make it work properly.
How can I do this?